# Merge 2 sound cards into one virtual driver

Tags: macos, audio, usb, driver, virtual

currently i am using Macbook Pro and Macosx 10.8.2
3 days ago , i bought a DJ controller soon after i realized that that controller hasnt got any buildin sound card.
i connect that device to macbook through usb port.
Everything is fine , i can do my mix using macbook builtin sound card and 5+1 sound system.But the problem is , Most djs do cue which means another sound output needed for their headphones in order to do a smooth transition between sounds.
so i bought a cheap usb sound card.and i plugged my headphone to that.

Mixing software is so dumb that it doesnt have any ability to manage two sound card at the same time.

So i figured out that if i write a virtual sound card driver that has two virtual stereo outputs , I could merge builtin macos sound card and usb sound card into the that virtual driver.

What i 've done so far :

started to read I/O Kit framework.

what i am planning to do:

actually i dont really understand which I/O Kit family to inherit
i may try first to implement PCI family or USB family inheritance to the driver
Another thing is , What i understood so far , in my virtual driver i must clearify device ids and devices' bus adresses in order to forward builtin card to virtual output1 and usb sound card to virtual output 2

any help would be appreciated 
just show me the lights , i can drive by myself.

Comment: See the answer below. Implementing aggregate device support as Apple has already done is much, much harder than it looks because the audio interface is the system audio word-clock master.  When there are two interfaces, one needs to slave to the other - or if that's not possible, sample-rate conversion is required.  This is the reason this feature is not widely seen in DAW packages or on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to write a driver or do any programming at all. Just create an aggregate device using the audio midi setup utility.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3956